# UI scaling across multi monitors are different

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr, dpi

I extended my primary display to a large monitor.
Now UI elements such as buttons, menus appear little larger on my monitor. How can I keep the same UI element sizes across both of my displays?

[Built in display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0MkJ.png)

[Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxoa0.png)

I have tried Gnome Tweak Tool to set font scaling. But it doesn't change sizes of UI elements.

Thanks in advance!